# C# - Find output

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have the following C# code below.

```
Object first = 5; 
Object second = 10; 
second = first;
Console.WriteLine(first + "    " + second);


 Object a = 3; 
 Object b = a; 
 a = 6;
 Console.WriteLine(a + "    " + b);
```

I get the following output:

```
5 5
6 3
```

Actually I am expecting "6 6" as the second set. Can anybody explain where I am wrong?

Regards,
Justin Samuel.

Comment: Nice question to an admission exam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
a = 6;
```

assigns `a` with the reference to a **newly** boxed int.
`b` keeps referencing the value (3) that was boxed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Object` variable will contain an `int` which is a *value type*. `a` and `b` will be two different instances, so changing the value of `a` (which essentially means to have `a` reference *a new int instance*) will not alter the value of `b`. You can alter your first code sample to produce a similar result:

```
Object first = 5; 
Object second = 10; 
second = first;
first = 8;
Console.WriteLine(first + "    " + second); // prints "8    5"
```

Comment: He does not change the (int) value of `a` but makes `a` reference a different object.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are value types, not references.

When you write this

```
object a = 3;
object b = a;
```

you assign the *value* 3 to b. The subsequently, with

```
a = 6;
```

you assign the *value* 6 to a, and b is not affected because it was assigned the *value* 3.

Comment: But `a` and `b` are references (to boxed int's).

Answer (score 0):

When you set a = 6,  its only setting a, b remains 3.
(this would be expected)

Answer (score 0):

```
static unsafe void Main()
    {

        Object first = 5;
        Object second = 10;
        second = first;
        Console.WriteLine(first + "    " + second);

        int i = 3;
        int y = 6;
        int* a = &i;
        int** b = &a;
        a = &y;
        Console.WriteLine(*a + "    " + **b);}
```

complit with /unsafe

```
5    5
6    6
```

:-). i'd not recommend to write code in this way though =)